# View all git activity on my local machine

Tags: git, devops

Is it possible to see all of my recent git activity on my local machine across all of my git repositories? I am generally working on multiple projects with different git hosting solutions (so I can't use GitHub's activity monitor) and I would like to review my recent work for keeping accurate records of what I'm working on.

Thanks!

Comment: Did a script for this reason https://github.com/ivarprudnikov/my_commit_history Also working on an app that'll do this in the browser https://app.gitactivity.com/

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if there is a onestop-shop for all your git activity...  I would go into whatever project directories you are worried about and run
`git log --author=yourName` to see your recent changes.

see [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but for my purposes I want to use it as a reminder / review of work I did...that would require me to actually remember which project i was working on, which is what I would be trying to figure out.

Comment: Sorry, you may find this helpful then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820167/is-there-a-git-activity-log

Comment: No apologies needed. Thanks for the insight! I might take some time this week to build a solution to this myself.